How do I set up fzf fuzzy finder to use ripgrep in Powershell?
Goal
I want to be able to invoke fzf in Powershell with Ctrl+T and it should use ripgrep so it's faster.
Context

I don't know what to set up in PowerShell_profile.ps1 to achieve the above goal.

Every time I make a search with Ctrl+T, the file search starts anew which takes time, instead of using some kind of cache:


The Internet suggests to make fzf use ripgrep

Both fzf and ripgrep are installed


My current Powershell_profile_ps1 file looks like this
# PSReadLine
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Windows
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete

# PSfzf
Import-Module PSFzf
# Override PSReadLine's history search
Set-PsFzfOption -PSReadlineChordProvider 'Ctrl+t' `
                -PSReadlineChordReverseHistory 'Ctrl+r'
# Override default tab completion
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -ScriptBlock { Invoke-FzfTabCompletion }



What I've found so far
Some blogs suggest to put this line in PowerShell_profile.ps1:
$env:FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'rg --files --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*"'

But I didn't notice any improvements even after restarting the Windows Terminal.

"But I didn't notice any improvements" - how are you measuring?

@MathiasR.Jessen, do you see the red box with "85955/309116" in the first screenshot? I just looked at that and used a stopwatch. It every time reindexed from 0 to 309116. But, Mathias, it could also be that that is as designed and I haven't understood how FZF works. A confirmation either way would be nice.
